# How to send information from a server to Android

Tags: android, spring, web-services

I've got a server. How can I send information from the server to my Android app? This is one of my controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping("/city/{cityId}")
public ModelAndView showCity(@PathVariable("cityId") int cityId){
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("city/cityDetails");
    mav.addObject(this.whatsNewService.findCityById(cityId));
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Improved spelling and grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this case you can not pass a ModelAndView (Actually you can). But the best option is to use REST. You can make this method a REST api method. and pass a Jason object.

In general, web applications expose their service through an REST api to be used by a third part applications or to power their mobile applications

```
@RestController
public class CityController {

   @Autowire
   private WhatsNewService whatsNewService;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/city/{cityId}")
   public City showCity(@PathVariable("cityId") int cityId){

    return this.whatsNewService.findCityById(cityId);
   }

}
```

Or you can use the same `@Controller` class and

```
@Controller
public class CityController {

   @Autowire
   private WhatsNewService whatsNewService;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/city/{cityId}")
   public @ResponseBody City showCity(@PathVariable("cityId") int cityId){

    return this.whatsNewService.findCityById(cityId);
   }

}
```

In android client side you can use RETROFIT like library to map your josn object to application object.